# Original error: DLL load failed while importing runtime:

Tags: python, dll, runtime-error, cupy

I'm using a library (pomegranate) and I want it to run in GPU, which required to install Cupy-CUDA. I have installed it by using install cupy-cuda111 (according to this [doc](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html), because my CUDA version is the 11.1).

I got this error at the "`import cupy`" line and I don't know how to solve it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andrea\.virtualenvs\workspace-ee5hg7DR\lib\site-packages\cupy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cupy import _core  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\andrea\.virtualenvs\workspace-ee5hg7DR\lib\site-packages\cupy\_core\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cupy._core import core  # NOQA
  File "cupy\_core\core.pyx", line 1, in init cupy._core.core
  File "C:\Users\andrea\.virtualenvs\workspace-ee5hg7DR\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cupy.cuda import compiler  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\andrea\.virtualenvs\workspace-ee5hg7DR\lib\site-packages\cupy\cuda\compiler.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cupy.cuda import device
  File "cupy\cuda\device.pyx", line 1, in init cupy.cuda.device
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing runtime: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andrea\Desktop\workspace\train11.py", line 16, in <module>
    import cupy as cp
  File "C:\Users\andrea\.virtualenvs\workspace-ee5hg7DR\lib\site-packages\cupy\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    raise ImportError(_msg) from e
ImportError: CuPy is not correctly installed.

If you are using wheel distribution (cupy-cudaXX), make sure that the version of CuPy you installed matches with the version of CUDA on your host.
Also, confirm that only one CuPy package is installed:
  $ pip freeze

If you are building CuPy from source, please check your environment, uninstall CuPy and reinstall it with:
  $ pip install cupy --no-cache-dir -vvvv

Check the Installation Guide for details:
  https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html

original error: DLL load failed while importing runtime: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
```

There it says that Cupy is not correctly installed, but I uninstalled and installed twice, and the error lasts.

python = 3.9.7

CUDA = 11.1

Linux (with pipenv)

Comment: The *.dll* or **some of its dependencies** could not be found. Check them using 
[Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com) or (newer) [\[GitHub\]: lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: Try setting `CUDA_PATH` environment variable to the CUDA installation path, e.g., `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1`.